# little endian processor and big endian processor - save number to memory

Tags: microprocessor, computer-architecture

Processor save `32` bits number`(123456780)_8` at address `1000`.  We would like to know what values are under addresses `1000` and `10001`.
a. little endian processor
b. big endian processor

First of all we must convert number to `16`: `0029CBB8`.
a.
`1000:29 00`
`1001:B8 CB`

b.
`1000:00 29`
`1001:CB B8`

Tell me please, if I am right ? If not, where I am wrong ?

Comment: Why are you splitting on 16bit boundaries. Endianness is about byte ordering, regardless of how that ends up being stored in memory words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using the octal value 012345670, which is the same as 0x0029CBB8 in C. This Wikipedia article on [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) should be helpful; see [Illustration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Illustration).

Are you running on a microcontroller architecture that addresses 16-bit words? Most microprocessors address individual bytes. (See your a/b illustration, it doesn't appear to be byte-addressable.)

Little-endian produces a byte order of B8 CB 29 00 from addresses 0 to 3. I'll leave big-endian up to you to work out.